# Different iPhone simulator sizes throwing nodes out of place

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite, skscene

I built my game on the iPhone 6 simulator, and everything was going fine until I needed to switch screen sizes for screenshots. I switched from the 6 to the 5s and now everything is in the wrong place and very off center. How do I make my game suitable for all screen sizes with everything in its place? Will post code if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

If you have hardcoded your view locations and sizes (as opposed to making everything relative to everything else) then you will either have to refactor to make everything relative or do some sort of scaling and letterboxing.

Comment: How do you define your views? Programmatically or in a storyboard file?

Comment: would you prefer to scale or letterbox? https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC500892.png

Comment: Scaling seems better. Is there that much of a difference?

Comment: do you have any example for letterbox/scaling ? @Slepz

Comment: find out what the pixel width and height is for the iphone 6 screen. keep that in your code as BaseX and BaseY. At runtime, find the screen with and height and store it as ScreenX and ScreenY. Make a functions called ScaleX() and ScaleY() which return BaseX / ScreenX and BaseY / ScreenY respectively. Everywhere you set a view's height or width with a hardcoded value, multiply that value by ScaleX or ScaleY depending on whether it's related to X and Width or Y and Height

Comment: Can you type this out in an answer in code? It makes sense, but I need a visual.

Comment: to do the letterboxing instead, figure out whether you should be letterboxing in the X or the Y and just add an offset instead of multiplying by a scale factor as described in the previous comment. Basically, you're multiplying your pixel values or offsetting them to fit the screen you're running on. I'd highly recommend refactoring if you have the time, but this will work if you don't want to

Comment: your code:

    `let textView : UITextField = UITextField(frame : CGRect(x:10, y:10, width: 10, height: 10 ))`

your new code: 

    `let textView : UITextField = UITextField(frame : CGRect(x:10 * ScaleX(), y:10 * ScaleY(), width: 10 * ScaleX(), height: 10 * ScaleY()))`

Comment: Is this SpriteKit compatible?

Comment: Oh wow sorry I didn't notice this was about spritekit. Spritekit should automatically handle letterboxing for you. look at this link.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/49695/sprite-kit-tutorial-making-a-universal-app-part-1