# iPhone 4, 5, 5s and 6+ simulators misaligning nodes

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

Apologies if I've already asked this, but Im very stuck; the first question was very unclear. Created a game in SpriteKit on the iPhone 6 simulator and when run the other sized simulators, everything is thrown out of alignment. Im not using any .sks, .xib or storyboarding. Is there a way to programmatically resize the game so that all screen sizes have the correct positioning? Will post code if necessary.

Edit: GameViewController:

```
   import UIKit
   import SpriteKit
  var sceneSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
 var screenWidth = sceneSize.width
 var screenHeight = sceneSize.height
  class GameViewController: UIViewController {
var scene: GameScene!

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()


    let skView = self.view as! SKView
    skView.multipleTouchEnabled = false
    scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
    //scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.ResizeFill
    skView.presentScene(scene)
    scene.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0)
    skView.showsFPS = false
    skView.showsNodeCount = false
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
           let completionBlock: () -> Void = {

    }

    let errorBlock: (NSError!) -> Void = { error in
        print("error")

}
    RevMobAds.startSessionWithAppID("", withSuccessHandler: completionBlock, andFailHandler: errorBlock);

}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        return .AllButUpsideDown
    } else {
        return .All
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

}

Edit 2 GameScene:

```
  import Foundation
 import SpriteKit
 import UIKit
    var sceneSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
   var screenWidth = sceneSize.width
   var screenHeight = sceneSize.height
    class GameScene: SKScene {

       player.position = CGPointMake(screenWidth / 5, screenHeight / 3)
       }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different iPhone simulator sizes throwing nodes out of place](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34363501/different-iphone-simulator-sizes-throwing-nodes-out-of-place)

Comment: I know, but it didn't answer my question.

Comment: @RaeTucker your question is exactly the same as your old question, instead of creating a new question, you really should just edit the old one.  I would delete the old question since it will offer no benefits to anybody.

Comment: Yes, i will, my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

First, set the GameScene SKSceneScalode (this is found pre-programmed into the GameViewController to .ResizeFill

Then copy the following code into GameScene:

```
Import UIKit
var screenSize = UIScreen.mainscreen().bounds
var screenWidth = screenSize.width
var screenHeight = screenSize.height
```

This will store the width and height of the screen in the variables screenWidth and screenHeight. Now when you create your spriteNodes and other objects, use these two variables as your basis. Here's an example

```
someNode.position = CGPoint(x: screenWidth/5 y: screenHeight/3)
```

Comment: It's still not working properly and I have what you answered verbatim.

Comment: Would you mind posting some code? The GameViewController first

Comment: If theres anything else you want to see, let me know.

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps try moving the screen size holder variables into the GameScene class. Just make sure you import UIKit into the class. If it still doesn't work, post the code for how you are declaring and adding the object into the view

Comment: @RaeTucker and how was the node declared?

Comment: In a  separate .swift file.

Comment: Did you remember to add the node with self.addchild()player

Comment: If that is there then post the .swift file in which the node is declared

Answer (score 0):

Are you the same person that posted on the Swift section of Reddit? Here's my code that works for all iPhone devices, as I  answered it well on the Reddit post the same way. Here's the more profound answer.

In your View Controller, enter the following code inside the viewDidLoad().

```
//Create a scene object with the max size of an iPhone 6 Plus at 1920 x 1080
//That means it can easily scale down to the 6, 5, and 4S.
let mainScene = GameScene(size: CGSize(width: 1920, height: 1080))

//To fill the scene and fit for all sizes
mainScene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

//Prepare the view
let mainView = self.view as! SKView
mainView.showsFPS = true       
mainView.showsNodeCount = true
mainView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

//Move to the required scene
mainView.presentScene(mainScene, transition: SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(1))
```

In the class scene, add the following variables at the top.

```
//Will be used to get the ratio of the device
let deviceWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
let deviceHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height
let maxAspectRatio: CGFloat
let playableArea: CGRect
```

If you don't already have an override init inside the class scene that the view is moving to, add the following inside the class.

```
//Overrides the superclasses' SKScene init
override init(size: CGSize) {

    //Initializes the maxAspectRatio variable
    maxAspectRatio = deviceHeight / deviceWidth
    print("The ratio of the device is: \(maxAspectRatio)")


    //Prepares the rectangle view that is viewable by the user (ONLY FOR PORTRAIT MODE)
    let playableWidth = size.height / maxAspectRatio
    let playableMargin = (size.width - playableWidth) / 2.0
    playableArea = CGRect(x: playableMargin, y: 0, width: playableWidth, height: size.height)

    /*USE THIS CODE IF YOUR APP IS IN LANDSCAPE MODE*****************************************
    let playableHeight = size.width / maxAspectRatio
    let playableMargin = (size.height - playableHeight) / 2.0
    playableArea = CGRect(x: 0, y: playableMargin, width: size.width, height: playableHeight)
    *///*************************************************************************************


    //Find out what kind of device the user is using
    if maxAspectRatio == (4 / 3) {

        //The iPhone's 4S ratio is 4:3
        print("The user is using an iPhone 4S")

    } else {

        //That means the ratio is not 4:3, so it probably is 16:9
        print("The user is using an iPhone 5, 6, 6S, or 6 Plus.")
    }

    //Assigns the size of the scene to the superclass init of SKScene
    //Must be called after all variables are initialed in this class
    super.init(size: size)
}
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

Add the following function inside the scene class too so you can see the viewable area that is seen by the user. It draws a red rectangle. Then, just call this function inside the didMoveToView() function. Now to position objects, all you have to do is use CGRectGet... properties on the playableArea to position the objects correctly.

```
//Used to draw the rectangle or the view of the phone
func drawPlayableArea() {
    let shape = SKShapeNode()
    let path = CGPathCreateMutable()
    CGPathAddRect(path, nil, playableArea)
    shape.path = path
    shape.strokeColor = SKColor.redColor()
    shape.lineWidth = 8
    addChild(shape)
}

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    drawPlayableArea()

    //Examples used to position objects on a screen related to the playable area or viewable area
    //This works for all iPhone devices as well as iPods.

    let label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Arial")
    label.fontColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
    label.text = "Hello, Redditor!"
    label.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(playableArea), y: CGRectGetMidY(playableArea))
    addChild(label)

    let score = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Arial")
    score.verticalAlignmentMode = .Top
    score.horizontalAlignmentMode = .Left
    score.fontColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
    score.text = "Score: 100"
    score.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMinX(playableArea) + 20, y: CGRectGetMaxY(playableArea) - 20)
    addChild(score)

    backgroundColor = SKColor.blackColor()
}
```

[Here are the github files if you need to understand the code more.](https://github.com/jozemite/SpriteKit-iPhone-Device-Ratios)

Screenshots of positions in an 4S and a 6 Plus. Notice how the objects stay positioned relative to the scene size.

[image: iPhone 4S] [image: iPhone 6 Plus]

Comment: Yes i am haha. I have nodes set up in a plist file, so giving them a position besides `(position.x, position.y)` would really screw everything up.  Is there a way to change that?

Comment: Well, I've never used plist files for object positions so if you're trying to make it work for several devices sizes, you might want to rethink your approach.

Answer (score 0):

OK I had time to reread this,  and I think I know what is going on,  I will leave my old answer in here as well.

New Answer:
  What is going on here is you are setting your scene size at the time of creation of view,  before any auto constraints get applied.  So your view size is not the same as your screen size.  Thus, your scene becomes the same size regardless of device,  then you apply the math based on your screen,  and everything gets thrown off.  What you need to do is 1) Verify that my theory is right, and that at the time of creating your scene,  the size is not the same as screen size, then 2)  create the scene at the time the view does get resized for the device.

Old Answer:
The reason everything is thrown out of alignment is because your game scene is being resized based on device.  You need to set a single constant size for doing things the way you are doing 
`let scene = GameScene(size:CGSizeMake(400,300))`
Where 400 x 300 can be changed based on your needs.  this will give you a play area of fixed size to work with, so your nodes will be placed the same.  Then, to handle the screen size,  you set your scenes scale mode to aspect fill or aspect fit,  depending on if you want to lose information, but have no black bars,  or have black bars and show all information. (resize fill will distort your image by stretching if that is what you want).  to do this  it is just `scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill`

Now you will have to tweak numbers and images if you are getting undesirable results,  but the same logic should be applied to all devices.  If you start grabbing things like the screen size again,  things will start misaligning.

Inside your scene code,  use the scenes width and height to manipulate your nodes, not the screen

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
   override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
   player.position = CGPointMake(scene.frame.width / 5, scene.frame.height / 3)
   }
```

Best way to think about it is the Game scene gets treated as its own screen,  and in the end you want to take this screen and scale it to meet the various device settings.

Comment: Okay,this makes sense, thank you. Is there a conditional I can use to set it to different screen sizes? (i.e code for different devices)

Comment: Okay, also I have nodes set up in a plist file (lots of them) and they're whats getting misaligned mostly. Is there a way to center them on all devices?

Comment: are nodes given specific positions? like (100,100)

Comment: Yes, in the plist file, but in the game scene their position is simply  `node.position = (CGPointMake(position.x, position.y))`

Comment: ok well if that is the case,  then you need to use my old answer.  What is your goal for the different devices,  do you want scaling, or more play area. Can you start a chatroom for this so that we are not flooding the comments?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98419/discussion-between-rae-tucker-and-knight0fdragon).